# addEventListener event Uncaught TypeError: e.stopPropogation is not a function

Tags: javascript

Adding event listener to a button throws

> Uncaught TypeError: e.stopPropogation is not a function

```
document.getElementById(`test`).addEventListener('click', (e) => this.handleOpen(e), false)
```

Handler

```
handleOpen = e => {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log(e)
  console.log(e.stopPropagation) //undefined
}
```

Comment: It's just a typo...

Comment: Damn, got it thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

You mistyped the propagation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

`stopPropagation`

Answer (score 1):

Typo. Should be e.stopPropagation